# VBA Macros Excel Opening PowerPoint: method open of object presentations failed

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm working on an excel file that involves opening up PowerPoint as a step. However, when I run it, it produces the error message "Method Open of Object Presentations Failed" When I click debug, it highlights the "Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open("DestinationPPT"). Please help. Any advice is sincerely appreciated.

```
'Powerpoint
Sub OpenPowerPoint()

Dim DestinationPPT As String
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation

'Template Location variable
DestinationPPT = HOME.TextBox2.Value
DestinationPPT = DestinationPPT & "\Gemba Template.pptx"

Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open("DestinationPPT")

'Transition from Excel to PowerPoint
Dim x, lastRow, slideNum As Integer
Dim cellName, shapeName, cellScore As String
```

[image]

Comment: Remove the quotes from `"DestinationPPT"` - it's a variable, not a string literal.

Comment: That didn't work :(

Comment: make sure `DestinationPPT` is a valid path. Otherwise, it will fail. To test `debug.print DestinationPPT` and see what the result is

Comment: The result gives a valid path to a folder/item on my desktop

Comment: did you triple check the path validility? can you copy / paste into Windows Explorer and it opens the files? Because this: `Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)` will work with a valid path.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your HOME.Textbox.Value contains a fully qualified file name, the only problem is you have mixed early object binding with late object binding.

```
'Powerpoint
Sub OpenPowerPoint()

Dim DestinationPPT As String
'You choose early binding, good choice
Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim myPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation

'Template Location variable
DestinationPPT = HOME.TextBox2.Value
DestinationPPT = DestinationPPT & "\Gemba Template.pptx"

'The CreateObject function is for late binding of objects
'You choose early binding.  In that case use New.
'Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Set PowerPointApp = New PowerPoint.Application
'Assuming HOME.Textbox.Value contains a fully qualified file string
'Remove the double quote marks since DestinationPPT is a vaiable not
'a literal
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(DestinationPPT)

'Transition from Excel to PowerPoint
Dim x, lastRow, slideNum As Integer
Dim cellName, shapeName, cellScore As String
```